# Manage yml configs from active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I need to edit yml files from Active Admin (database.yml, memcached.yml and others).

Are there any gem to solve this problem? If no, how can it be solved? Or maybe there are any way to keep config data in database instead of yml (anything but database.yml)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying settings in yaml files that are checked into the repository doesn't sound like a good thing to do. I suggest to store settings in a datastore like a database using http://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings

See also [Ruby on Rails - Storing application configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127960/ruby-on-rails-storing-application-configuration)