# How to properly store and access global app configuration settings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

in the cause of writing a rails 4 app I've been wondering lately about where and how exactly to store custom configuration information? Specifically I mean things like *App title*, *special email addresses*, maybe *theming options* etc. which I want to refer to throughout my app using either environment variables or other constructs. I've been digging around a little and - *before deploying* - ended up using a nifty initializer creating an OpenStruct like this

```
require 'ostruct'                                                                                                                                                                    

all_config = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/app_config.yml") || {}
env_config = all_config[Rails.env] || {}
AppConfig = OpenStruct.new(env_config)
```

which reads the following yaml-file (app_config.yml)

```
default: &default                                                                                                                                                                    
  general:
    app_title: MyName
    maintainer_email_address: someone@somewhere.org

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
```

Within development I was totally happy accessing everything I had to access via `AppConfig.general.*` but unfortunately this does not work out in production, trying to start a server/console ends up in raising  an `Uninitialized constant AppConfig`-error.

Now I have two to three questions:

1) Can I assume that this does not work in production due to the load-order of files, where `production.rb` becomes loaded *before* the initializer (-> AppConfig as a global variable is not present)

2) If yes: Why does this work in development? Whats different there?

3) What's a good practice to store information like the above? My wish is to be able to get and set information like these comfortably via some kind of user/admin interface. From there I don't want to mess with my environment-file too hard...

Allright, I hope somebody can help me out there, thanks in advance!
Andi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127960/ruby-on-rails-storing-application-configuration/40306232#40306232

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately it's not answering questions 1 and 2. Do you have any clue on that?

Answer (score 1):

Add your configuration file in `RAILS_ROOT/config` directory.

```
# config/foo.yml
development:
 api_key: 'my_development_api_key'

staging:
  api_key: <%= ENV['API_KEY'] %>

production:
  api_key: <%= ENV['API_KEY'] %>
```

Add initializer file in `RAILS_ROOT/config/initializers` directory

```
# config/initializers/foo.rb
foo_config = Rails.application.config_for(:foo)

Rails.application.configure do
  config.foo = ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions.new
  config.foo.api_key = foo_config[:api_key]
end
```

Use your configuration in your code.

```
Rails.configuration.foo.api_key
```

Sometimes you can't commit your secret keys and other credentials in code. In this situation, use environment variables. I use [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem to manage environment variables.